# Obliques asymptotes of a function

Tags: calculus, limits

$f:[0,\infty)\to R, f(x)=\sqrt{x^2+x\ln{(e^x+1)}}$

I have this function and i need to find out the asymptotes to $+\infty$ (+infinity)

i calculate the horizontal ones, and they are $+\infty$

i can't calculate the limits at the obliques asymptotes

Comment: $+\infty$ cannot be a vertical or horizontal asymptote.

Comment: i know that they are not i mean that the limit is +∞

Comment: Where exactly did you get stuck? Can you show us your steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find the oblique asymptote in the direction of positive infinity, then do this:

$$
a=\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}=
\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x^2+x\ln{(e^x+1)}}}{x}=\\
\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x^2+x\ln{(e^x+1)}}}{\sqrt{x^2}}=
\lim_{x\to+\infty}\sqrt{1+\frac{\ln{(e^x+1)}}{x}}=\\
\sqrt{1+1}=\sqrt{2}.
$$

$$
b=\lim_{x\to+\infty}(f(x)-ax)=
\lim_{x\to+\infty}\left(\sqrt{x^2+x\ln{(e^x+1)}}-\sqrt{2}x\right)=0
$$

The second limit is more difficult to calculate, but it equals $0$.

Plugging all this information into the equation $y=ax+b$, we get:
$$y=\sqrt{2}x.$$

Comment: can you explain why ln(e^x+1) / x is 1 ? please

Comment: Again, you can use L'Hôpital's rule to find it. Do you know how to use it? If your problem is really just those limits, then post a separate question for each one asking how to evaluate them. And don't forget to explain where exactly you get stuck with them.

Comment: i know but for all the square i need to use it ? like it isn't take me so far

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't really understand what you're saying. I think you're asking whether L'Hôpital's rule should be used for the whole expressing including the square root? Correct? No. Only for $\frac{\ln(e^x+1)}{x}$. Because that's the limit you want to find at the moment. It just happens to be part of a bigger expression.

Comment: all this time i was thinking that i was needed to apply L'Hopital's rule for all √ - square but now i get it that i need to do it just for the fraction

Comment: @xirunicole $$\ln{(e^x+1)}=\ln{(e^x)}+\ln{(1+e^{-x})}=x+\ln{(1+e^{-x})}\to^{(x\to\infty)}x+\ln{(1)}=x$$

Comment: Or you can forgo L'Hôpital's rule altogether and instead use the much neater way to find it kindly suggested by Peter Foreman.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

When $x$ is large, $e^x$ is much larger then $e^x+1 \sim e^x$, then ....

Comment: the problem is at $f(x) / x$

Answer (score 0):

*Hint*.

$$ \lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac {\sqrt {x^2 + x \ln (e^x + 1)}} x = \lim_{x \to +\infty} \sqrt {\frac {x^2 + x \ln (e^x + 1)} {x^2}} = \lim_{x \to +\infty} \sqrt {1 + \frac {\ln (e^x + 1)} x} $$

Can you go on from here?

Comment: actually there i am, i dont know why ln(e^x+1) / x is 1